# Loading Training Images using Keras

Tags: keras

To train a model using Keras, should I load all the images I have to an array to create something like

```
x_train, y_train
```

Or  is there a better  way to read the images on the fly while training. I am not looking for ImageDataGenerator class since my output is an array of points not classes based on directory names..

I managed to get my data csv file to contain the array of points and image file name in 9 columns as follows:

x1 x2 ..... x8 Image_file_name

Comment: What's the problem with ImageDataGenerator? Your question is extremely broad, you need to add details so it is answerable.

Comment: I explained the problem up to my understanding.

Comment: No, you haven't, for example, there is no information on how the labels are currently stored.

Comment: I have 9 columns, 8 for data values (x,y coordinates for the 4 points I am labeling)  and one for the image file name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this data with `ImageDataGenerator`. You incorrectly assume that it needs folders for classes, but that only applies to `flow_from_directory`. The method `flow_from_dataframe` allows you to load data from a Pandas dataframe, from where you can load your data, for example:

```
idg = ImageDataGenerator(...)
df = pd.load_csv('your_data.csv')
generator = idf.flow_from_dataframe(directory='image folder', x_col = 'filename_column',
                                    y_col = ['col1', 'col2', ..., 'coln'],
                                    class_mode='other')
```

This generator will data from the dataframe, load the image filename in `directory` as specified by the value of `x_col`, and use the corresponding row to build the targets, which in this case will be a numpy array of the values of columns in `y_col`. More information about this method can be found in the [keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow_from_dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

Loading the entire data set in memory in an array is not a great idea because the memory consumption could go out of control, so you should use a generator. ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_dataframe are a great way of loading images in Keras. Since you don't want to use ImageDataGenerator(can you mention why?) you can create your own generator function that loads chunks of images in memory. If you load your data in a generator make sure you use fit_generator and predict_generator functions.

To load unlabeled data you can do the following hack:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_data = datagen.flow_from_directory('.', classes=['directory_where_images_are_stored'])
```

For more information check out link [1].

[1] https://kylewbanks.com/blog/loading-unlabeled-images-with-imagedatagenerator-flowfromdirectory-keras

Comment: Up to my understanding ImageDataGenerator works where the whole image is labeled ( classification as in dogs vs cats example). My output is an array of points as in Kaggle facial keypoint detection.

Comment: my classes are not based on the directory ,the output is an array of 4 (x,y) points

Comment: one thing here, is how we know the order of the images, to match the labels